# Facebook oauth display popup

Tags: facebook, oauth, popup

I use this
 \ a class="fb-button" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=184082381694xx8&redirect_uri=https://xxxxxxx.com&display=popup" \
although it seems to changing the way the oauth displayed it doesn't open as a pop up but
as a new tab.
How can I do a popup facebook login like this one https://www.airbnb.com/login ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the Facebook JS SDK for those popups to work correctly. Instructions on [how to include the SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) are available in the developer documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I did including the javascript SDK as avist suggested. Here are the conclusions of my experience/research:

- I couldn't get display=popup to work, this is not surprising as many things in the facebook doc don't really seem to work.
- Airbnb (in the example Sergi linked to) implements their own popup. There is a pretty good example of how to do it here http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/create-facebook-popup-authentication-window-using-php-and-javascript/ . In a nutshell you just open the link in a popup using javascript, and then close the window when the user accepts the permissions and make sure the parent window gets redirected.

I ended up using  FB.signup from the JavaScript API, mush simpler to use. The only down side is that you get a short-lived token( 2 hours) and opposed to longed-lived token(60 days). But you can always exchange the short lived for a long lived - https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token